# Print page not working when button click

Tags: javascript, php, printing

I created a PHP page to print invoice of my project. I need to print this page automatically after saving my invoice. I used jquery $.post method to open print.php page,

**Save invoice button**

```
$.post("print.php",{
    desc: $desc,
    }, function(data,success){
    alert(success);
});
```

and i used javascript `window.onload = function(){window.print();}`in print.php page. but its not working, nothing printing. Then i open print.php page in browser and it was printed as i want.I don't need to redirect to print.php page.
Is there anything wrong in my code. How to print this page ?

**Edit**

I don't need to save or get result from this `$.post`. I just need to print invoice with `desc` data.

Answer (score 0):

Problem:The page is not loading so window.onload will not work.This is because you have posted with ajax.
Solution:Try posting the invoice details by using a form.

Comment: Thanks. I don't need to post data. I already saved data using ajax. I need to print a invoice. `desc` is a description about invoice. I need to print invoice with description

Answer (score 0):

Try chaining a `done()` after the `post()`.

```
$.post( "print.php", { desc: invoiceData })
   .done(function( data ) {
       alert( "Success: " + data );
});
```

**Heads up!**

Alert the results from requesting `print.php` using `done()` instead of `success()` because: **The `jqXHR.success()`, `jqXHR.error()`, and `jqXHR.complete()` callback methods are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use `jqXHR.done()`, `jqXHR.fail()`, and `jqXHR.always()` instead.**

Comment: Thanks. I don't need to get any result. I just need to print invoice.

Comment: The `data` in `alert( "Success: "  + data );` is response for the client  from the `print.php` upon ajax `done()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print the response of ajax then use below code.

```
$.post("print.php",{
        desc: $desc,
    }, function(data,success){
        alert(success);
        w=window.open(null, 'Print_Page', 'scrollbars=yes'); 
        w.document.write(data); //where data = response of print.php, the invoice
        w.document.close();
        w.print();
    }
);
```

**NOTE**: I'm assuming that if I open print.php in browser then I will get the invoice in a human readable manner, either a raw text or html whatever you will see by opening print.php in browser that will be printed as it is.